# GDK Authentication Process of Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

In Google Glass Application using GDK

GDK Authentication Process

1. When users turn on your Glassware in MyGlass, they are redirected to your authentication URL. These requests include a query parameter named userToken that you need to use later.

**not getting the UserToken**

Warning: Do not store this user token. It is only for use by Google's authentication endpoints to map the request back to the originated user during that session only and does not contain any information that can be used to persistently identify the user. The token is not guaranteed to be the same if the user authenticates with the same Glassware multiple times or if the user authenticates with different Glassware from the same developer.
The user enters their credentials on your authentication page.

2. Your server validates the user's credentials. If the credentials are valid, make a Mirror API call to the mirror.accounts.insert method. This method requires that you specify the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth scope when you build your Mirror service object. Examples of making this API call using either raw HTTP or Java are shown in the account creation examples.

Using thridparty Server Authentication
At the time of Creating the Account from Mirror API

From where should i get the Parameter ? like
1. User token 
2. AuthType
3. AuthToken
4. AccountName

what parameter should I send?

```
 /**
  * Creates an account and causes it to be synched up with the user's Glass.
  * This example only supports one auth token; modify it if you need to add
 * more than one, or to add features or user data or the password field.
 *
 * @param mirror the service returned by getMirrorService()
 * @param userToken the user token sent to your auth callback URL
  * @param accountName the account name for this particular user
  * @param authTokenType the type of the auth token (chosen by you)
  * @param authToken the auth token
  */
 public static void createAccount(Mirror mirror, String userToken, String accountName,
    String authTokenType, String authToken) {
    try {
     Account account = new Account();
     List<AuthToken> authTokens = Lists.newArrayList(
        new AuthToken().setType(authTokenType).setAuthToken(authToken));
     account.setAuthTokens(authTokens);
     mirror.accounts().insert(
        userToken, ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountName, account).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

please help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the parameters origin:

- The `userToken` you get from MyGlass when the user clicks on the auth URL: if you don't get it, let the review team know so that they can fix whatever is missing in the backend. Make sure to specify that you want to use GDK auth.
- The `accountName` is up to you: this is the name of the user account you are inserting.
- The `authTokenType` is also up to you but need to exactly match what you provided the review team with.
- The `authToken` is the token generated by your service: again, this is the token you are inserting for the user.

Comment: Can you please specify the authTokenType and authToken in detail or can you give us some example for both parameter.

Comment: An example `authTokenType` would be `com.example.token`, this is really up to your application (e.g the Google `authTokenType` is `com.google`). The `authToken` is a token that is generated by your application, there are no real example I can provide you.